# How to reference ListView DataPager from code-behind

Tags: asp.net, listview, paging, datapager

For a ListView control DataPager, I'm trying to programmatically set the [PageSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datapager.pagesize.aspx), but from the code-behind, I'm not able to see the datapager.

Trying to do this:

```
DataPager1.PageSize = 10
```

But "DataPager1" isn't accessible from the code behind page.

Thanks,
Adam

Answer (score 1):

If your DataPager is inside the ListViews LayoutTemplate it is not directly accessible from codebehind.

To get access to the DataPager, you must use the ListViews FindControl method.

```
DataPager pager = YourListViewID.FindControl("DataPager1") as DataPager;
```

Remember to check if the pager object is found (different from null) before using it.